# Is listening to hypnosis tracks dangerous while driving?

Tags: hypnotism

I've been listening to hypnosis tracks on spotify recently. [Example (warning: Spotify).](https://play.spotify.com/album/72M9Zl3IkQ23SAO7xdDVut)

Almost all of these tracks start with a disclaimer telling you not to listen to the track while driving or operating heavy machinery.

Is there any evidence that hypnosis tracks can actually be dangerous, or is this just marketing?

Comment: Closely related (duplicate?): http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/can-a-hypnosis-audiobook-induce-epileptic-seizures

Comment: Any sort of droning monotonous sound can make a person drowsy. It has nothing to do with hypnosis